# Metaplot of Vampire: The Masquerade V20

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-20th-anniversary

The 20th Anniversary edition of Vampire: The Masquerade is, with respect to the rules, almost the same as the (revised) second edition of the game (see the answer here: [What are the major changes made to Vampire: The Masquerade for its 20th Anniversary edition?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10834/what-are-the-major-changes-made-to-vampire-the-masquerade-for-its-20th-annivers)).

But where does the metaplot of V:TM V20 stand? I mean, is it possible to say, that the metaplot of V20 is the same as the metaplot of V:TM after book X? Or are there some major changes, so that it does not fit in into the original metaplot?

Comment: Why, out of curiosity, did you add the [tag:onyx-path]? What does it add//change about the question?

Comment: To this question, nothing. But I think there will be more questions about the onyx-path in the future (since currently there is nothing concrete known about it). It is not even known if there will be metaplot in the onyx-path or not.

Comment: so if it adds nothing, why tag it as such?

Comment: I believe V20 could be considered the first Onyx Path product though I'm not 100% on that

Comment: The Onyx Path is a marketing term from White Wolf regarding the creation of new product for the classic WoD setting. I don't think it has much value as a tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The metaplot has been rolled back to a state somewhere **between that of Second Edition and that of Revised**. The Gangrel are a Camarilla clan; the Ravnos have not been devastated; Gehenna is still somewhere off in the distance. However, the Malkavian clan description shows them with Dementation as their third discipline and the Tremere *antitribu* have vanished. Many of the "possible futures" are detailed in sidebars, so you can see where the metaplot had gone in the past, but with no obligation to follow it.

Comment: A bit of note in terms of the metaplot. According to the recent news from onyxpath the V20 metaplot situation will be used as a base for the post Gehenna V4 of vampire and thus is the current state of the metaplot in total.

Answer (score 1):

They have with Beckett's Jyhad Diary an own Metaplotbook which makes some retcons to characters and let the world experience the week of nightmares but not the dawn of Gehenna. On page 428 in the core rulebook there is even a description of the clans after the metaplot.