# Difference in Core Mechanics between Revised Edition and W20?

Tags: world-of-darkness, edition-comparison, werewolf-the-apocalypse

I've joined a long running group playing Werewolf but whereas I've got the 20th Anniversary PDF rulebook they're playing from the Revised Edition rulebooks and supplements. I'd like to discuss the differences with the group and maybe persuade them to take up the newer rules where appropriate.

I can see that Dodge and Athletics are separate skills in their version but what other differences in the core mechanics should I be aware of?

When I say core mechanics I'm excluding all the various gifts, merits, and flaws as they only apply in specific cases, it's the general rules I'm thinking of.

Comment: To clarify the editions:  Werewolf: The Apocalypse has had four editions.  1st Edition, 2nd Edition, Revised Edition (sometimes colloquially called 3rd Edition), and the 20th Anniversary Edition (often abbreviated W20).

Comment: Some partial answers here: [What are the major changes made to Vampire: The Masquerade for its 20th Anniversary edition?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/10834)

Comment: Keep in mind that until a question gets answers, the site will automatically bump it every once in a while. Sometimes a question about something obscure, hard, or (like this question) requiring a long answer takes time to find the expert who can answer well.

Answer (score 4):

### Attributes & Abilities

- *Leadership* has been become a Talent.
- *Dodge* has been removed as a skill; its former functionality has been moved to *Athletics*.
- *Larceny*, *Academics* and *Technology* have been added.
- *Linguistics* is no longer a skill; each language known is a 1-dot Merit instead. (p. 484)

### Breeds

Extra beginning gifts to choose from. No other changes.

### Auspices

More beginning gifts!

### Tribes

Again more beginning gifts for all tribes or some slight reorganisations (Bone Gnawers). Backgrounds have been clarified into discouraged or restricted (for example: the Silent Striders had a very ambiguous description).

- For the *Bone Gnawers* Resources has become discouraged instead of restricted. This gives you the option of having certain backgrounds at character creation, without explicitly requiring storyteller approval.
- *Get of Fenris* : Contacts are discouraged
- *Glass Walkers* : Mentor is discouraged
- *Red Talons* : There are no Homid Red Talons (in Revised you could argue for their existence), Allies & Contacts have become discouraged.
- *Shadow Lords*: Allies & Mentor have become discouraged.
- *Silent Striders*: Resources has become discouraged.
- *Stargazers* : are back! Allies, Fetish & Resources have become discouraged.
- *Wendigo*: Contacts & Resources have become discouraged.

### Systems

- The sample table for gaining renown has been recompiled (more examples & different types of renown can be gained / lost through an action).
- The rules for "splitting one's action" in a turn have been clarified (lose a die from each action in that turn & each action beyond the first losses an extra die).